# SessionNotCreatedException when trying to connect to Selenium Standalone Server in Docker container

Tags: python, docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am encountering a SessionNotCreatedException issue when attempting to connect to a Selenium Standalone Server running in a Docker container.

```
pip show selenium

Name: selenium
Version: 4.15.2
Summary: 
Home-page: https://www.selenium.dev
Author: 
Author-email: 
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/jun/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: certifi, trio, trio-websocket, urllib3
Required-by: 
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

docker ps
29ba302ef8eb   selenium/standalone-chrome:latest   "/opt/bin/entry_poin…"   13 minutes ago   Up 13 minutes             0.0.0.0:4444->4444/tcp, 5900/tcp   remote_chromedriver

curl http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/status

{
  "value": {
    "ready": true,
    "message": "Selenium Grid ready.",
    "nodes": [
      {
        "id": "a0f1d0c6-bdff-4122-a273-94bbb54d0817",
        "uri": "http:\u002f\u002f172.27.0.5:4444",
        "maxSessions": 1,
        "osInfo": {
          "arch": "amd64",
          "name": "Linux",
          "version": "6.4.16-linuxkit"
        },
        "heartbeatPeriod": 60000,
        "availability": "UP",
        "version": "4.15.0 (revision 1d14b5521b)",
        "slots": [
          {
            "id": {
              "hostId": "a0f1d0c6-bdff-4122-a273-94bbb54d0817",
              "id": "a2815b34-595b-48da-9773-c06e3303c6c6"
            },
            "lastStarted": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "session": null,
            "stereotype": {
              "browserName": "chrome",
              "browserVersion": "119.0",
              "platformName": "linux",
              "se:noVncPort": 7900,
              "se:vncEnabled": true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }%
```

Test Python code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
remote_webdriver = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'

def main(driver):
    title_element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h3.tts_head')
    title = title_element.text
    print(f"Page Title: {title}")

with webdriver.Remote(remote_webdriver, options=options) as driver:
    # Scraping part
    driver.get("https://n.news.naver.com/mnews/article/005/0001606450")
    time.sleep(5)
    main(driver)
```

Encountered a SessionNotCreatedException:

```
SessionNotCreatedException                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 20
     17     title = title_element.text
     18     print(f"Page Title: {title}")
---> 20 with webdriver.Remote(remote_webdriver, options=options) as driver:
     21     # Scraping part
     22     driver.get("https://n.news.naver.com/mnews/article/005/0001606450")
     23     time.sleep(5) 

File /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/jun/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:208, in WebDriver.__init__(self, command_executor, keep_alive, file_detector, options)
    206 self._authenticator_id = None
    207 self.start_client()
--> 208 self.start_session(capabilities)

File /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/jun/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:292, in WebDriver.start_session(self, capabilities)
    285 """Creates a new session with the desired capabilities.
    286 
    287 :Args:
    288  - capabilities - a capabilities dict to start the session with.
    289 """
    291 caps = _create_caps(capabilities)
--> 292 response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
    293 self.session_id = response.get("sessionId")
    294 self.caps = response.get("capabilities")
...
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor$NewSessionRunnable.handleNewSessionRequest (LocalDistributor.java:824)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor$NewSessionRunnable.lambda$run$1 (LocalDistributor.java:784)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:829)
```

1. Verified that the Selenium Standalone Server container is up and running.
2. Checked the selenium/standalone-chrome container logs for any potential issues, but nothing stands out.
3. Restarted the Docker container to rule out temporary glitches.